# Visitation and Permanent residence in Canada

Tags: visas, residency

I am anticipating entering Canada as a visitor, but might be interested in becoming a permanent resident.  Can I apply for permanent residency while on a visitor's visa?

Comment: Welcome to Travel.SE! This question will fit our sister site [Expatriates](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com) better so will surely be transferred there.

Answer (score 1):

Except for a few special circumstances, you cannot apply for residence while visiting Canada. A temporary visa is *temporary* and you would have to satisfy the immigration authorities that you will *leave* the country. If your intention is emigration, you may want to explore how to [become a Canadian resident](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/new-immigrants/pr-card/understand-pr-status.html)

> [Becoming a permanent resident of Canada](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/extend-stay.html)
>
> To stay in Canada as a permanent resident, you must leave the country and apply from outside Canada, except in the special cases listed below. To become a permanent resident, you must meet Canada's immigration requirements.
>
> You can apply to become a permanent resident from inside Canada if you:
>
> - are a [refugee or a protected person](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/refugees.html),
> - are a [spouse or common-law partner of a Canadian citizen or permanent resident](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/immigrate-canada/family-sponsorship/spouse-partner-children.html),
> - are a [live-in caregiver](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/work-canada/permit/caregiver-program/extend-change-permit.html#resident),
> - hold a valid [temporary residence permit](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/application/application-forms-guides/application-permanent-residence-temporary-resident-permit-holder.html) or
> - are applying under the [Canadian Experience Class](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/immigrate-canada/express-entry.html).
>
> Find more information about [becoming a permanent resident](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/new-immigrants/pr-card/understand-pr-status.html).